# Множественная подмена слов в Sublime Text

Tags: sublime-text

Необходимо в txt файле с несколькими миллионами текстовых строк найти несколько сотен слов и заменить каждое из этих слов на скорректированное.

К примеру, нужно найти ВСЕ слова "красный", "желтый", "зеленый" и заменить каждое из встреченных слов на "синий", "фиолетовый", "малиновый" соответственно. Т.е. "красный" заменить на "синий", "желтый" на "фиолетовый" и "зеленый" на "малиновый".

Можно ли это сделать средствами Sublime Text?

Answer (score 1):

> К примеру, нужно найти ВСЕ слова...

Если всё-таки ВСЕ слова, то нажимаете `Ctrl + H`, в верхней строчке пишете `красный`, в нижней - `синий` и жмёте кнопку `Replace All`. Таким образом, вручную для замены каждого из трёх цветов на другой вы нажмёте эту кнопку только по одному разу. Смущает только общий объём файла в несколько миллионов строк.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте регулярные выражения [Sublime Text](https://sublimetext.ru/documentation/find-and-replace)

Comment: Мне нужно заменить порядка 8 тысяч слов на 8 тысяч других слов в файле с 9 миллионами строк. Обычной заменой мне придётся воспользоваться 8 тысяч раз. Подскажите, какое конкретно регулярное выражение мне может помочь?

Comment: А кнопка "Replace All" запрещена? Или вам необходимо сделать замену, но не всех вхождений этих слов?

Comment: @RomanTretyakov, такие вещи надо писать в вопросе.

Comment: @Quazimorda, полагаю, он имеет в виду 8000 _разных_ слов (причём то, на что их заменять, тоже отличается).

Comment: @SergeiNazarenko, ну и как регулярные выражения могут помочь сделать хотя бы то, что написано в вопросе?

Comment: @Qwertiy Строго говоря, автор написал, что таких слов несколько сотен, а не 8к, но как-то сильнее ускорить процесс едва ли возможно, ибо пары для замен так и так придётся записывать. *UPD* - в комменте увидел про 8к.

Comment: @Quazimorda, я почему-то по вопросу подумал, что речь о нескольких сотнях вхождений, а не пар для замены.

Comment: В данном случае несколько сотен или 8000 - роли не играет. Все равно руками "Replace All" даже 100 раз делать - это жесть. В excel есть функция ВПР (VLOOKUP), когда идет поиск ряда значений и замена каждого на другое. Надеялся что Sublime Text есть что-то подобное. Спасибо за ответы! Буду искать другое решение.